# Retrieving full objects from a query done via Bolt protocol

Tags: java, neo4j, protocols

In Neo4J, I want to use the bolt protocol.
I installed the 3.1 version of Neo4J.
I my Java project, that already works well with normal HTTP Rest API of Neo4J, I integrate with Maven the needed drivers and achieve to perform request with BOLT.

The problem is everywhere you make a search about bolt they give example like this one :

MATCH (a:Product) return a.name

But I don't want the name, I want all the data of all product, what ever i know or not before what are these columns, like here:

MATCH (a:Product) return * --> here I retrieve only the ids of nodes

I found there https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/tree/master/neo4j-jdbc-bolt we can "flatten" the result but it seems to not work or I didn't understand how it works:

GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost:7687/?flatten=-1", AuthTokens.basic( "neo4j", "......." ) );

I put the ?flatten=-1 at the end of my connection address... but that changed nothing.

Anyone can help? Or confirm it's not possible or not working ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understood my error, I didn’t dig enough in the object returned. So used to have a JSON formatted response, I didn’t see that I have to search in the StatementResult object to find the wanted object with its properties. In fact Eclipse in the “expressions” shows “in fly” only the ids, but inside the object data are there.

Record oneRecord = rs.next();
String src = oneRecord.get("m").get("source");

That way I can reconstruct my object